# How does importing libraries in Java work

Tags: java

I'm starting to program in Java and I can't quite understand how importing libraries works.

Suppose I need to import a library in order to be able to write a specific program. I save it in my PC.

How is someone who does not have the same library on their machine supposed to be able to run the program? This is probably a silly question, but I really am new to programming.. Thanks.

Comment: It depends how you are going to distribute your program. For instance, you might give them a `jar` file with the dependencies included.

Comment: Importing a library just means you can use code in that library, provided it is available when you run.

Comment: Who is "someone"? A customer, colleague user, colleague developer?
Is he using a java ide or do you want to distribute your software with an installer or do you want use a shell / bat extension to start the java program?

Comment: @tak3shi suppose it's a customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need a java runtime (JRE) installed.

Third party libraries like apache commons, accompany your application jar.

```
myapp.jar
lib/apache-commons.jar
lib/ido.jar
```

The myapp.jar (zip format) contains a METAINF/MANIFEST.MF containing an entry

```
Main-Class: ...
Class-Path: lib/apache-commons.jar, lib/ido.jar
```

And with that `myapp.jar` is an executable jar.

A build tool like **maven** can be used to build such a distribution: take care of library versions (dependencies), preparing the manifest, generate to output folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited the question, because I think I did not express what I meant too well the first time. Could you re-read it please?

Comment: You have to pack all, typically in a subfolder like `lib` above, for further distribution. In the simplest case in a .zip file a user might unpack. And then clicking the application jar, java will using the `MANIFEST.MF` find a `lib/courserajava.jar`. Look in your IDE's target, dist or other build directory to see what the IDE produces.

Answer (score 0):

"*Someone who does not have the same library on their machine*" is a wrong concept. A machine has to have the **Java Runtime Environment (JRE)** installed on it in order to run a Java program (i.e., to execute the .class file). The JRE contains all the Java libraries. Therefore, every machine running Java has every library that you can possibly use in your program.

Importing a library in your program is basically instructing the compiler to include that library in the program. You don't really save the Java program on your PC with the libraries in it. It's just a set of instructions. These instructions are given to the Java platform on any machine the program is run on. While running the program, the JRE on that machine uses the libraries as instructed in the .class file.

I hope I could make it clear to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited the question, because I think I did not express what I meant too well the first time. Could you re-read it please?

Comment: @uzytkownik1234 You just changed your question. You shouldn't do that. In case you want to edit your question, ADD new stuff to the existing question. Do not REMOVE stuff from your question as you've done. Acknowledge that users spend time in helping people out and the answers are meant to be helpful to future visitors. I have flagged this post for moderator intervention.

Comment: You're mistaken. I added a few sentences, but did not remove anything.

Comment: @uzytkownik1234 Yeah. My bad. However, please add a heading to the edit in your question. My answer is still affected the way I said. And I'm sorry for having mistaken it. Please add something like 
`EDIT` followed by the new contents. Again, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Please refer to the answer by Joop Eggen

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, have a look at the libraries, which are found by:

1. right click on project
2. build path
3. configure path
4. libraries

You can check weather the JRE is added to your project or not

If it's not present click on add libraries and add it

Comment: There is no build path when i right click on project ;-)

Comment: rigth click on project go to properties and to java build path